# 415 Unaccepted Media Type Maven Not Working

Tags: java, maven

I converted my ReST web project into a maven project using eclipse and I keep getting this error (415 Unsupported Media Type) when I run it on Tomcat. Any idea on what I could be doing wrong? I am thinking I have an incorrect path in my post/action method in my index.jsp file, but I am not entirely sure because the path was the same for the ReST project and it worked perfectly fine.

This is the beginning of my class:

```
import com.triprates.*;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;

@Path("error")
public class RestWeb {
    @GET    
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String getText() {
        return "<body> Error. Invalid data. </body>";
    }

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    @Path("/inputvalues")
    public String getParamText(@FormParam("travel") String travel,
            @FormParam("start") String start,
            @FormParam("duration") String end, 
            @FormParam("party") String people) {
        String returnString = processInput(travel, start, end, people);
        return "<body> " + returnString + " </body>";
    }
```

my pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>mavenProject</groupId>
<artifactId>mavenProject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers </groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet </artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs </groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api </artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject </groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2 </artifactId>
        <version>2.28</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have an index.jsp file as well that has my post/action method and a web.xml. Am I missing a dependency that is causing this error?

Comment: I should also clarify, when I run it on tomcat, it brings up my project, but when I put in input values, submit query and it posts the path from the index.jsp page (localhost:8080/MavenProject/web/error/inputvalues), that is when I get the 415 error

Comment: Could you include an example of the requests you're sending, for example cURL? Is your content-type header `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: Additional info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST

Comment: This error indicates that the client is sending a request body with a content-type that the server doesn't expect. Perhaps there is some JavaScript code running on form submit that is sending JSON instead of form data? We'll need to see `index.jsp` (at least the part that contains  the form) and any JavaScript files it references to give more specific advice. Please edit the question and add those.